# How do I get nested JSON values in c#?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have the following JSon string returned from a service:

```
{
    "links": {
        "data": {
            "self": {
                "body": "",
                "content_type": "",
                "href": "",
                "method": "GET",
                "name": ""
            }
        }
    },
    "results": [{
        "data": {
            "categories": {
                "41370_10": "abc",
                "41370_11": "abc",
                "41370_2": "abc",
                "41370_5": "abc"
            }
        },
        "metadata": {
            "categories": {
                "41370": {
                    "key": "41370",
                    "name": "123"
                },
                "41370_10": {
                    "bulk_shared": false,
                    "key": "41370_10",
                    "name": "some name"
                },
                "41370_11": {
                    "allow_undefined": false,
                    "key": "41370_11",
                    "name": "some name 2"
                },
                "41370_2": {
                    "key": "41370_2",
                    "key_value_pairs": false,
                    "name": "some name 3"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "data": {
            "categories": {
                "72051_2": "asd",
                "72051_3": "asd"
            }
        },
        "metadata": {
            "categories": {
                "72051": {
                    "key": "72051",
                    "name": "some name 4"
                },
                "72051_2": {
                    "key": "72051_2",
                    "name": "some name 5"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "data": {
            "categories": {
                "112644_2": "zxc"
            }
        },
        "metadata": {
            "categories": {
                "112644": {
                    "key": "112644",
                    "name": "some name 6"
                },
                "112644_2": {
                    "hidden": false,
                    "key": "112644_2",
                    "name": "some name 7"
                }
            }
        }
    }]
}
```

How do I process this data to get a nice, plain Dictionary? It would look something like this:

```
{"some name", "abc"}, 
{"some name 2", "abc"}, 
{"some name 3", "abc"},
{"some name 5", "asd"},
{"some name 6", "zxc"}
```

Currently trying to use c#, json.net, with scarce success.
Any help greatly appreciated.

Update 1:
I've gotten as far as getting the JTokens out of it, but am not sure how to separate the data from metadata (yes, I realize how absurd that sounds).

```
//get json object
JObject cjob = JObject.Parse(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);

IEnumerable<JToken> categorymetadata = cjob.Descendants()
    .Where(t => t.Type == JTokenType.Property && ((JProperty)t).Name == "categories")
    .SelectMany(p => ((JProperty)p).Value);
```

Comment: `process this data` == deserialize

Comment: You need a JSON parser look at [JSON.NET Lib](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json). If you have tried the same library (or not), then post the code of what you have so far for us to help.

Comment: Ok. My current attempt posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following [LINQ-to-JSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm) query should give you the result you are looking for:

```
Dictionary<string, string> dict = cjob["results"]
    .Children<JObject>()
    .Select(result => result.SelectToken("metadata.categories").Children<JProperty>()
                            .Join(result.SelectToken("data.categories").Children<JProperty>(),
                                  metaCat => metaCat.Name,
                                  dataCat => dataCat.Name,
                                  (metaCat, dataCat) => new
                                  {
                                      Name = (string)metaCat.Value["name"],
                                      Value = (string)dataCat.Value
                                  }
                            )
    )
    .SelectMany(a => a)
    .ToDictionary(a => a.Name, a => a.Value);

foreach (var kvp in dict)
{
    Console.WriteLine(kvp.Key + ": " + kvp.Value);
}
```

This does an inner join between the categories in the `metadata` object and those in the `data` object for each result and selects the joined properties into a list (IEnumerable really) of anonymous name-value pairs.  The lists of pairs are then flattened down to a single list and finally placed into a dictionary.

I am making the following assumptions about your data:

- each result object will always have both metadata and data
- the category names and data values will always be strings
- the category names will be unique across all results

If these assumptions don't hold you will run into errors and will need to make adjustments to the code.

Here is a working demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/WkztV5

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using the JsonConvert.DeserializeObject you can Deserialize your json into objects and then do what ever you want with those object for example:

```
public class Account
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public IList<string> Roles { get; set; }
}

string json = @"{
'Email': 'james@example.com',
'Active': true,
'CreatedDate': '2013-01-20T00:00:00Z',
'Roles': [
'User',
'Admin']
}";

Account account = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Account>(json);

Console.WriteLine(account.Email);
// james@example.com
```

https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeObject.html

If you want to convert your json into objects without figuring it out:
http://json2csharp.com/
is a really nifty tool just copy and past your json into there.

In your case you will have a root object like this:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public Links links { get; set; }
    public List<Result> results { get; set; }
}
```

and you can just look through your results to get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's easy to do it like this, but I only had a couple levels in the JSON heirarchy

```
dynamic deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject((string)data);
newObj = deserialized["objName"].value == null ? "" : deserialized["objName"].value;
```